# Vue: When importing a particular component I receive a Type Error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am currently creating a SPA using Vue, and I am using a UI framework called [Vue Argon Dashboard Pro](https://demos.creative-tim.com/vue-argon-dashboard-pro)

I am trying to import this particular component called [**Select**](https://demos.creative-tim.com/vue-argon-dashboard-pro/documentation/plugins/select.html).

Based on the documentation it says I just need to add the following lines.

```
    import { ElSelect, ElOption } from "element-plus";
    export default {
      components: {
        [ElSelect.name]: ElSelect,
        [ElOption.name]: ElOption
      }
    }
```

Now when I add them to an isolated page, I would receive the following errors.

> [vue-router] Failed to resolve async component default: TypeError:
> Object(...) is not a function
>
> [vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation:
>
> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

These errors aren't giving me any clue what am I doing wrong because I have other pages with other components that are working well, and this component is just the one not working properly.

Here's my **Test.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <el-select placeholder="Single Select" v-model="selects.simple" filterable>
      <el-option
        v-for="option in selects.languages"
        class="select-danger"
        :value="option.value"
        :label="option.label"
        :key="option.label"
      >
      </el-option>
    </el-select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ElSelect, ElOption } from "element-plus";

export default {
  name: "TestPage",
  components: {
    [ElSelect.name]: ElSelect,
    [ElOption.name]: ElOption
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selects: {
        simple: "",
        languages: [
          { value: "Bahasa Indonesia", label: "Bahasa Indonesia" },
          { value: "Bahasa Melayu", label: "Bahasa Melayu" },
          { value: "Català", label: "Català" },
          { value: "Dansk", label: "Dansk" },
          { value: "Deutsch", label: "Deutsch" },
          { value: "English", label: "English" },
          { value: "Español", label: "Español" },
          { value: "Eλληνικά", label: "Eλληνικά" },
          { value: "Français", label: "Français" },
          { value: "Italiano", label: "Italiano" },
          { value: "Magyar", label: "Magyar" },
          { value: "Nederlands", label: "Nederlands" },
          { value: "Norsk", label: "Norsk" },
          { value: "Polski", label: "Polski" },
          { value: "Português", label: "Português" },
          { value: "Suomi", label: "Suomi" },
          { value: "Svenska", label: "Svenska" },
          { value: "Türkçe", label: "Türkçe" },
          { value: "Íslenska", label: "Íslenska" },
          { value: "Čeština", label: "Čeština" },
          { value: "Русский", label: "Русский" },
          { value: "ภาษาไทย", label: "ภาษาไทย" },
          { value: "中文 (简体)", label: "中文 (简体)" },
          { value: 'W">中文 (繁體)', label: 'W">中文 (繁體)' },
          { value: "日本語", label: "日本語" },
          { value: "한국어", label: "한국어" }
        ]
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Here is my **Router.js** file as this was pointed out the issue on the other question raised

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";

Vue.use(Router);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/test",
    name: "TestPage",
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "bundle.test" */ "@/views/Test.vue")
  }
];

const router = new Router({
  mode: "history",
  routes
});

export default router;
```

Hoping all those details help. Thank you

Comment: If you remove the components imports from `Test.vue`, does the page work? I understand the error as Vue-router not being able to dynamically import `@/views/Test.vue`.

Comment: Yup, @Kapcash. Just plainly importing the component and not even using it on the render will trigger the error. So it looks like the component is the issue right?

Comment: And if you import statically `@/views/Test.vue` in router.js, it triggers the same error right?

Comment: Same error @Kapcash. Do you think the component itself is the source of the issue?

Comment: That's what I was trying to check on. Are you using Vue 3 for your app?

Comment: Yup, I am using Vue 3 @Kapcash

Comment: Sorry I'm clueless here. I suggest you open an issue on their github for better help: https://github.com/element-plus/element-plus/issues